# If folder exist create shortcut this folder in MyDocuments VBS

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I want to create a shortcut in my documents only if will be existed  a network share.
I'm trying to solve for a long time, but i still have problem with this.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim strSkanSou  
Dim objMyDocuments 

strSkanSou = "\\Network\Scan\%username%"

IF strSkanSou.FolderExists then

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objMyDocuments = objShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") 
Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(objMyDocuments & "\Skaner.lnk")

objLink.Description = "Skaner"
objLink.TargetPath = strSkanSou
objLink.Save 


End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got most of it solved already. You just need to create a `FileSystemObject` to check for the existence of your folder. Replace:

```
IF strSkanSou.FolderExists then
```

With:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strSkanSou) Then
```

Also, I see you're using the prefixes `str` for *string* and `obj` for *object*, which is great, but you may want to use `strMyDocuments` instead of `objMyDocuments`, since this is actually a string and not an object.